# Meteor verification, enrollment, etc. email via 3rd party mailer

Tags: meteor

I'd love to have Meteor use a 3rd party API (in my case, Mandrill) for `sendVerificationEmail`, `sendEnrollmentEmail`, etc. Has anyone gotten this working?

EDIT: Specifically, I'd like to use templates I have in Mandrill for these system emails. I imagine that I'll have to change some functions in the Accounts package to send names, tokens etc. to Mandrill via an API call. If anyone has done this already, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to send the template?

Comment: Nope. After consulting some others, I decided it made more sense to retain control.

Comment: Sounds like you have given up on this quest? those that provided answers don't sound like they understand what you are trying to do though. 
I don't think using mandrill template will make you relinquish control though. There are merge tags or dynamic contents. We just need to figure out how to tell meteor to use that template.

Answer (score 4):

Super easy to do this with the [mandrill](http://atmospherejs.com/package/mandrill) package on atmosphere

```
meteor add timmyg13:mandrill
```

Then its just setting it up on your server side:

```
# in server code
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Meteor.Mandrill.config({
        username: "YOUR_MANDRILL_USERNAME",
        key: "YOUR_MANDRILL_API_KEY"
    });
});
```

And you're set!

The way it does this is it sets your smtp url to the mandrill smtp server, so anything using Meteor's email package will work (like accounts-password)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I'm doing right now (although without even using the Mandrill package). What I'd like to do is have my app use a Mandrill template to send much prettier versions of the basic emails. I'll edit the question to make this more clear.

Comment: the package didn't worked for with the accounts package, do you know if is still working? 
seems to me that the basic gist is just to change the process.env.MAIL_URL, but no deal at all and no errors are thrown
 @Akshat

Comment: this.process.env.MAIL_URL = "smtp://{{username@hotmail.com}}:{{Apikey}}@smtp.mandrillapp.com:587/";

Comment: @JulioMarins If you use this method don't forget to uriencodecomponent your username & password

Comment: @JulioMarins does your host allow outgoing SMTP email? Perhaps try sending the email from another package/nodejs to test. Your issue may not be related to a coding issue if no errors were thrown when the email was sent

Comment: I think it was a clash between packages of email, i removed all of them and just used the the process.env.MAIL_URL with the correct params for the mandrill and it worked. Thanks @Akshat for the help!

Answer (score 1):

just change "process.env.MAIL_URL" variable and use something like this:

```
this.process.env.MAIL_URL = "smtp://{{foobar%40gmail.com}}:{{apikey}}@smtp.mandrillapp.com:587/";
```

the package that @Akshat said do just that, and as he mentioned the username and apikey should be generated with "encodeURIComponent"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to user your templates, the trick is:

1) Have Mandrill Render them via the wylio:mandrill package.
2) Send the rendered html/text via Meteor's accounts package.

See this link for some example code: https://forums.meteor.com/t/sending-meteors-verification-email-with-mandrill/7485